# Submitting a search form on Bootstrap demo using $('form').submit(function(event))

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm following this guide to make a navigation bar which features a search facility using Bootstrap: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/GXb7V

It doesn't seem possible to submit the form although I understand this is intentional based on this code and it's comment:

```
// ONLY FOR DEMO // Please use $('form').submit(function(event)) to track from submission
// if your form is ajax remember to call `closeSearch()` to close the search container
$(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active button[type="submit"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this).closest('form'),
    $input = $form.find('input');
    $('#showSearchTerm').text($input.val());
    closeSearch()
});
```

How can you get the form to post to a script or URL and where does the js go to do this? Sorry if this is a basic question but there's no documentation on the above link that helps in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've figured this one out.

The issue is that the function `closeSearch()` in their js has the following line of code:

```
$form.find('input').val('');
```

I'm not sure what their intention was but the effect is that it ends up clearing the search input, so essentially you're submitting nothing. Commenting that out solves the issue of nothing being submitted.

In terms of the actual form submission itself commenting out

```
//event.preventDefault();
```

fixes that.